# Ignore inputs with more than one-element and then terminate. (Before pressing enter)

Tags: python, input, io

In my script,  If the **input-length** is **> 1**. It outputs NO and then terminates.

This is what I tried.

```
import re
N = input("Enter your integer N: ")
if len(N) > 1:
    print('no')
    quit()
```

Take notice that the *if statement* is not encountered before input, this does not allow me to instantly terminate before pressing enter. I want to instantly terminate the script once I give more than one element.

Output

```
Enter your integer N: 10
no
```

Intended results after trying to enter 10. ( See that my script is intended to ignore more than one-element)

Output

```
    Enter your integer N: 1
    no
```

With this restriction, the space-complexity will truly be O(1).

### Question

Is there some function in python that will restrict the input as I intend?

Comment: No there is not. However there are some OS-specific ways of reading single characters, like `msvcrt.getch()` for Windows, which would provide a way for you to limit it.

Comment: @martineau That's a shame.  An O(1) algorithm cannot be truly O(1) without O(1) space. Especially there is a user-input because inputs are not fixed. (in my case, the computer takes more than O(1) time to store the input as memory)

Comment: Generally one isn't concerned with computational complexity when dealing with user input, so you comment doesn't really make any sense (to me).

Comment: @martineau I apologize, what I'm trying to say is that storing 1-million bits takes more time than storing 1-bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: Travis:That's O(n) complexity—and not really that bad (although not as good as O(1)). I think you may need to [edit] your question and ,make what you're asking more clear…

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a Θ(2) space:

```
import readchar

x = readchar.readchar()
rest = readchar.readchar()
if rest != '\r':
    print('no')
    quit()
```